# the type or namespace XmlDictionaryReadercould not be found

Tags: c#

I am new in the .net world. So I really be glad for some help.
I try to get the message body (in wcf BeforeSendReply) with `xmlDictionaryReader`.
I get the error "the type or namespace `XmlDictionaryReader` could not be found.
I add in my program:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
```

and it still not working. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll`: Right click on Project within Solution Explorer -> Add Reference.

And for sure - C# is case sensitive, so it has to be `XmlDictionaryReader` and it looks like you started class name from lower letter: `xmlDictionaryReader`.

Answer (score 1):

you will need add reference to `Sytem.Runtime.Serialization.dll` in your references and

```
using System.Xml;
```

you should be able to then do

```
var temp = XmlDictionaryReader.Create(yourstream);
```